# SQL Server 2008 and Visual studio 2010 for Developers

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

I was looking for a development edition for both Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008, so I came up with the following:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Professional ($449.99)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0038KTO8S)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition ($49.95)](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Developer-Edition/productID.221634300)

I just wonder are the above editions have all what I need such as: will the Visual Studio have (e.g. .Net framework- local virtual server, etc...) and the SQL Server will have the engine and the ability to be used from Visual Studio and created all type of structures (tables, view, stored procedure, jobs, etc...)

Comment: Note: VS11 (aka VS 2012) is coming out in a few days (well, a few weeks for non-MSDN subscribers); you *might* want to consider whether waiting for that is a better option.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Pro comes with SQL Server **Express** - this is totally free, works like a charm, is only basically limited by database size and the amount of RAM it can use for query execution etc - but for development, it's more than enough, really ....

Comment: Also: check whether your VS 2010 pro includes "MSDN Essentials", as that **might already include** access to SQL Server Developer Edition edit: Yup, see the amazon page: "MSDN Essentials Subscription Included
 ... provides access ... and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 ..."

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, SQL Server is now at version 2012, and the developer edition costs the same.. so why get 2008 when 2012 is the latest version?

Second, Your needs may be taken care of by the Express editions, of both SQL Server and Visual Studio.  Both are free.  But you will need to evaluate your needs and compare them to the express edition features.

Third, Visual Studio 2012 is about to be released within the next couple of days, so you might want to wait for that as well.

Comment: VS 2012 is only "next couple of days" for msdn/technet subscribers; IIRC retail will be a few more weeks

Comment: Thanks guys, What I understand that I can use the free express edition but what are the limitation(e.g. Can I make as many web services as I want, as many pages as I want)(in other words whats the difference between the express and developer editions?). I have two questions: 1- Is there any technical problems when running the express editions on a real website?   2- Is (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) includes c# as code behind of the aspx or is limited to VB?    Thanks again

Comment: There are no licensing restrictions on code you produce in the express editions of visual studio.  The only limitations are around what features visual studio offers.  For example, you cannot use plug-ins like Resharper in the express edition.  You can create as many web sites or servers as you want.  It's free, just download it and use it.. If it works for you, then don't look back.